# Scatter Plot with 3 Variables in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple use case:

I have 3 variables, x, y and z.

I want to plot z as a function of x and y, so a 3D plot.

Comment: So you have two options or one option?

Comment: @NicolasGervais 2D plot would be better,so one option reallt

Comment: The example in the documentation would be [this one](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_demo2.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Regarding your two options, here's a reusable example of a 3D plot where `z` and the color are a function of `x` and `y`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(20)
y = np.random.rand(20)
z = x*y

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, z,
           linewidths=1, alpha=.7,
           edgecolor='k',
           s = 200,
           c=z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or, here's an example where `z` is a function of `x` and `y`, but in 2D only.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(20)
y = np.random.rand(20)
z = x*y

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.scatter(x, y,
           linewidths=1, alpha=.7,
           edgecolor='k',
           s = 200,
           c=z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! could you post the code for the 2d plot as well?

Comment: Yes sorry, somehow I forgot it.

Comment: is there a way to add a legend to those colors? (so I know what each color actually stands for?)