# Changing size of scatter plot points by value

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to make a scatter plot and scale the size of points on the basis of numbers from a different list.

So I am making a scatter plot of `y` vs `x` but the size of each point will depend on the corresponding number from `s`. Essentially, the larger the value of the element from `s` bigger would be the point on the scatter plot.

```
y = [2.2, 3.1, 4.3, 4.9, 5.1]
x = [0.03, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
s = [48, 134, 391, 203, 193]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable

Comment: [It's in the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html?highlight=scatter#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter).

Comment: @IvanCalderon thanks! Is there any way something similar could be done in 3-D?

Comment: @VedanthSriram shure, you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232073/scatter-plot-with-3-variables-in-matplotlib. But please try to review older questions first before opening new ones with similar topics

Comment: @IvanCalderon - sure. Apologies - I'm new to the site, but I can understand how irritating such questions can be.

Comment: @VedanthSriram They are not irritating. You just need to get used to how things work in SO, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

You are so close

```
ax.scatter(x, y, s=s)
```